# MacOS python command not finding active Conda environment from VS Code terminal

Tags: python, macos, visual-studio-code, conda

I recently got a new M1 MacBook - first time ever using a Mac - and immediately [downloaded Miniconda](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/install/macos.html) to get it set up for some Python work.

I created some virtual environments (e.g. `conda create -n myenv python=3.8`) but when active, the `python` command defaults to Mac's Python 2.7, preventing me from running scripts from the command line in VS Code. For example:

```
conda activate myenv
(myenv)% which python
 /usr/bin/python
```

`where` shows me the default 2.7 installation and the correct virtual environment version, but I can't access it.

```
(myenv)% where python
/usr/bin/python
/Users/user/miniconda3/envs/myenv/bin/python
```

Any idea how to get VS Code to find the proper Python version? It seems to work from the built in terminal, just not VS Code.

OS: Monterey 12.2.1

VS Code: 1.65.0

Miniconda: 4.10.1

Comment: Have you solved the problem?

Comment: Solved it this morning. Had some VS Code updates and an OS update, did both and it started working as expected. Unfortunately, not too helpful for anyone else who might encounter this.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try to take advantage of `python3` instead of `python` in the MacOS?

Or you can try to rename the `python.exe` to something others, such as `python2.7` under the `/usr/bin/python`?

Answer (score 0):

So the problem is, that in windows, you can change the path, but in mac there is this thing, that if you don't select the version, for example:

```
sudo python test.py
```

It will run Python 2.7, because it is installed, and it runs the lowest installed version. So try using

```
sudo python3 test.py
```

or specify the version in the terminal

```
sudo python3.8 test.py
```

Comment: This doesn't get around the issue with the virtual envs. `where python3` shows `/usr/bin/python3` (which I assume is my base conda installation) and my virtual env python3. So if I have packages in my venv that are not in my base env, then I still can't run it from the command line. Any `python` command points to two interpreters when I have the env activated.